# How to print out different values from same key?

Tags: perl, key-value

I have a two hashes with the same key but different values.

%HASH1

```
ERROR MESSAGE1 => A1
ERROR MESSAGE2 => A2
ERROR MESSAGE3 => A3
ERROR MESSAGE4 => A4
```

%HASH2

```
ERROR MESSAGE1 => C4
ERROR MESSAGE2 => C5
ERROR MESSAGE3 => C6
ERROR MESSAGE4 => C7
```

My code looks like this

```
my %errordata;
for my $key (keys %hash1) {
    $errordata{$key} = [ $hash2{$key}, $hash1{$key} ];
}

use Data::Dumper; 
print Dumper \%errordata;
```

So, my question is how can I print the values without the first hash's values based on the code above? because I tried doing a `while` loop but it shows the `ARRAY(0x2113a30)` instead.

```
while (my($g,$w) = each %errordata)
{
   print "$_" for @{$w};
}
```

Thank you.

**EDIT**

output should something like this

```
ERROR MESSAGE: ERROR MESSAGE1
FULL PATH: A1
LINE: C4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please investigate following piece of code for compliance of your problem.

NOTE: `while( my($g,$w) = each %errordata )` will not order pairs base on key order
(use `for` with `sort keys %errordata` instead)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my %hash1 = ( 
    'ERROR MESSAGE1' => 'A1',
    'ERROR MESSAGE2' => 'A2',
    'ERROR MESSAGE3' => 'A3',
    'ERROR MESSAGE4' => 'A4'
);

my %hash2 = (
    'ERROR MESSAGE1' => 'C4',
    'ERROR MESSAGE2' => 'C5',
    'ERROR MESSAGE3' => 'C6',
    'ERROR MESSAGE4' => 'C7'
);

my %errordata;

for my $key (keys %hash1) {
    $errordata{$key} = [ $hash2{$key}, $hash1{$key} ];
}

use Data::Dumper; 
print Dumper \%errordata;

say '--- Loop while --------------';
while (my($g,$w) = each %errordata)
{
    say 
"ERROR MESSAGE: $g
FULL PATH: $errordata{$g}[1]
LINE: $errordata{$g}[0]";
}

say '--- Loop for ----------------';
for( sort keys %errordata ) {
    say 
"ERROR MESSAGE: $_
FULL PATH: $errordata{$_}[1]
LINE: $errordata{$_}[0]";
}
```

Output

```
$VAR1 = {
          'ERROR MESSAGE3' => [
                                'C6',
                                'A3'
                              ],
          'ERROR MESSAGE2' => [
                                'C5',
                                'A2'
                              ],
          'ERROR MESSAGE1' => [
                                'C4',
                                'A1'
                              ],
          'ERROR MESSAGE4' => [
                                'C7',
                                'A4'
                              ]
        };
--- Loop while --------------
ERROR MESSAGE: ERROR MESSAGE3
FULL PATH: A3
LINE: C6
ERROR MESSAGE: ERROR MESSAGE2
FULL PATH: A2
LINE: C5
ERROR MESSAGE: ERROR MESSAGE1
FULL PATH: A1
LINE: C4
ERROR MESSAGE: ERROR MESSAGE4
FULL PATH: A4
LINE: C7
--- Loop for ----------------
ERROR MESSAGE: ERROR MESSAGE1
FULL PATH: A1
LINE: C4
ERROR MESSAGE: ERROR MESSAGE2
FULL PATH: A2
LINE: C5
ERROR MESSAGE: ERROR MESSAGE3
FULL PATH: A3
LINE: C6
ERROR MESSAGE: ERROR MESSAGE4
FULL PATH: A4
LINE: C7
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for this. I didn't know that I can print out the hash based on the elements. Really appreciate your answer and I'll try to use sort from now on.

Answer (score 2):

Your code until it builds `%errordata` hash looks fine.

While retriving the data from `%errordata`, you're expecting it to print values as `FULL PATH` and `LINE` as values for each key called `ERROR MESSAGE`.

You can use `foreach` loop to print them.

```
...
foreach my $key( sort keys %errordata ){
    print "ERROR MESSAGE: $key\n";
    print "FULL PATH: $errordata{$key}[1]\n";
    print "LINE: $errordata{$key}[0]\n";
}
```

Since `LINE` and `FULL PATH` would be always your hash of arrays 1st and 2nd element respectively.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the suggestion. I just realized if what happens if there is more than 1 element inside the first and second hash? can the `foreach` loop be applicable for that?

Comment: @AlyssaLow : You must edit/asknew question with possible cases.

Comment: hi, i edited my question. Could you please take a look at it?

Comment: @AlyssaLow Since you already opened a new question, I would recommend you to edit this question with initial version and you can accept any of the favorable answer if those matches your criteria.

Comment: Sure, no problem.