# Printing multiple hash value

Tags: perl, hash, key-value

Yesterday, I asked if it's possible to print out something like this.
**LINK:** [How to print out different values from same key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64692736/how-to-print-out-different-values-from-same-key)

The element A1 and B1 has the same key, which is also the same as `C4` and `D1`. However, `A1` is paired with `C4` and `B1` is paired `D1`. Thank you.

```
%HASH1

ERROR MESSAGE1 => A1, B1
ERROR MESSAGE2 => A2, B2
ERROR MESSAGE3 => A3, B3
ERROR MESSAGE4 => A4, B4

%HASH2
    
ERROR MESSAGE1 => C4, D1
ERROR MESSAGE2 => C5, D2
ERROR MESSAGE3 => C6, D3
ERROR MESSAGE4 => C7, D4
```

The expected output would like this

```
ERROR MESSAGE: ERROR MESSAGE1
FULL PATH: A1
LINE: C4

ERROR MESSAGE: ERROR MESSAGE1
FULL PATH: B1
LINE: D1
```

So I tried to figure out the code and it looks something like this.

```
my %errordata;
for my $key (keys %hash1) {
    $errordata{$key} = [ $hash2{$key}, $hash1{$key} ];
}

use Data::Dumper; 
print Dumper \%errordata;
while (my($k,$v) = each %hash){
print "ERROR MESSAGE: $k\n";
print "PATH: $hash{$k}[0][0]";
print "LINE: $hash{$k}[1][0]";
}
```

so my question is how do I make the numbers increment automatically which is the `[0][0]` and `[1][0]`? Should  I use a `for loop` like `C`? and if so, how should I implement it to my code above? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slight code modification and the problem solved.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my %hash1 = ( 
    'ERROR MESSAGE1' => ['A1','B1'],
    'ERROR MESSAGE2' => ['A2','B2'],
    'ERROR MESSAGE3' => ['A3','B3'],
    'ERROR MESSAGE4' => ['A4','B4']
);

my %hash2 = (
    'ERROR MESSAGE1' => ['C4','D1'],
    'ERROR MESSAGE2' => ['C5','D2'],
    'ERROR MESSAGE3' => ['C6','D3'],
    'ERROR MESSAGE4' => ['C7','D4']
);

my %errordata;

for my $key (keys %hash1) {
    $errordata{$key} = [ $hash2{$key}, $hash1{$key} ];
}

use Data::Dumper; 
print Dumper \%errordata;

say '--- Loop while --------------';
while (my($g,$w) = each %errordata)
{
    say 
"ERROR MESSAGE: $g
FULL PATH: $errordata{$g}[1][$_]
LINE: $errordata{$g}[0][$_]
" for 0..1;
}

say '--- Loop for ----------------';
for my $k ( sort keys %errordata ) {
    say 
"ERROR MESSAGE: $k
FULL PATH: $errordata{$k}[1][$_]
LINE: $errordata{$k}[0][$_]
" for 0..1;
}
```

Output

```
$VAR1 = {
          'ERROR MESSAGE4' => [
                                [
                                  'C7',
                                  'D4'
                                ],
                                [
                                  'A4',
                                  'B4'
                                ]
                              ],
          'ERROR MESSAGE3' => [
                                [
                                  'C6',
                                  'D3'
                                ],
                                [
                                  'A3',
                                  'B3'
                                ]
                              ],
          'ERROR MESSAGE1' => [
                                [
                                  'C4',
                                  'D1'
                                ],
                                [
                                  'A1',
                                  'B1'
                                ]
                              ],
          'ERROR MESSAGE2' => [
                                [
                                  'C5',
                                  'D2'
                                ],
                                [
                                  'A2',
                                  'B2'
                                ]
                              ]
        };
--- Loop while --------------
ERROR MESSAGE: ERROR MESSAGE4
FULL PATH: A4
LINE: C7

ERROR MESSAGE: ERROR MESSAGE4
FULL PATH: B4
LINE: D4

ERROR MESSAGE: ERROR MESSAGE3
FULL PATH: A3
LINE: C6

ERROR MESSAGE: ERROR MESSAGE3
FULL PATH: B3
LINE: D3

ERROR MESSAGE: ERROR MESSAGE1
FULL PATH: A1
LINE: C4

ERROR MESSAGE: ERROR MESSAGE1
FULL PATH: B1
LINE: D1

ERROR MESSAGE: ERROR MESSAGE2
FULL PATH: A2
LINE: C5

ERROR MESSAGE: ERROR MESSAGE2
FULL PATH: B2
LINE: D2

--- Loop for ----------------
ERROR MESSAGE: ERROR MESSAGE1
FULL PATH: A1
LINE: C4

ERROR MESSAGE: ERROR MESSAGE1
FULL PATH: B1
LINE: D1

ERROR MESSAGE: ERROR MESSAGE2
FULL PATH: A2
LINE: C5

ERROR MESSAGE: ERROR MESSAGE2
FULL PATH: B2
LINE: D2

ERROR MESSAGE: ERROR MESSAGE3
FULL PATH: A3
LINE: C6

ERROR MESSAGE: ERROR MESSAGE3
FULL PATH: B3
LINE: D3

ERROR MESSAGE: ERROR MESSAGE4
FULL PATH: A4
LINE: C7

ERROR MESSAGE: ERROR MESSAGE4
FULL PATH: B4
LINE: D4
```